# In netstat tcp is listening for SSH, but tcp6 is not listening, In sshd_config, i have both ipv4 and ipv6 what will the problem?

Tags: networking, kernel

While running the SSH demon, only ssh for tcp is listening, tcp6 is not getting listened, even though sshd_config file contains both Ipv4 and Ipv6.

Due to this, ssh demon is not replying for ipv6 ssh.

```
netstat -l
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN

netstat -nat
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

sshd_config file includes the follow,

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::
```

I have used the same sshd_config file in another linux desktop, there its listening for both ipv4 and ipv6.

Comment: Hi philip, I have addressed the comment. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `AddressFamily any` in sshd confiuration file

Comment: Hi Angel, I have tried the same, its not working.     

AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::

Comment: check `sudo sshd -T | grep -i address`